# Need simple working pom.xml file for wsconsume

Tags: web-services

I am using Java8 and I am trying to consume webservice using jboss plugin.

I have tried https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBWS/wsconsume  and ran into lot of compatibility issues

The problem is I am having lot of  dependency error all the time and I am now fed up. The current error is Failure to find com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:1.1. My concern is do i need these many dependency to run simple wsconsume?

```
<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
   <id>JBOSS</id>
   <name>JBoss Repository</name>
   <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.jbossas</groupId>
   <artifactId>jboss-as-client</artifactId>
   <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
   <type>pom</type>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

   <plugin>
   <groupId>org.jboss.ws.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-jaxws-tools-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
   <executions>
   <execution>
   <id>My execution</id>
   <goals>
   <goal>wsconsume</goal>
   </goals>
   <configuration>
   <wsdls>
   <wsdl>mylocation?wsdl</wsdl>
   </wsdls>
   <targetPackage>src</targetPackage>
   </configuration>
   </execution>
   </executions>
   <dependencies>

   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.ws.native</groupId>
   <artifactId>jbossws-native-client</artifactId>
   <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
   <type>jar</type>
   <scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.1</version>
   <type>jar</type>
   <scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.ws</groupId>
   <artifactId>jbossws-spi</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.4.Final</version>
   <type>jar</type>
   <scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>

   </dependencies>
   </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by executed the wsconsume.bat with exec-maven-plugin instead of **CRAPY JBoss plugin**

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>runbatchfile</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <executable>${env.RH-SSO}/bin/wsconsume.bat</executable>
          <arguments>
            <argument>-o</argument>
            <argument>${project.build.directory}\classes</argument>
            <argument>C:\my.wsdl</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```